# Weekday of the month trigger/schedule in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to create trigger on 4th weekday of the month in ADF pipeline. I could only come closed to first Monday of the month as shown below. But that is not enough for us.

[image]

Comment: That's actually a fairly complex trigger, I doubt you'll be able to work out direct support. I think you'd have more success running the pipeline on a daily trigger, then calling an Azure Function that returns True if "today" meets your criteria. Then use the AF return value in an If Condition activity that contains your workload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the answers before.
Given below seems optimal. One trigger is enough. It will execute 3 days. And an azure function to check if 'today' is the 4th workday.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with @Joel Cochran.

I think the easiest way is that you could create 5 triggers for this pipeline:

[image]

- Tigger 1: Forth Monday;
- Tigger 2: Forth Tuesday;
- Tigger 3: Forth Wednesday;
- Tigger 4: Forth Thursday;
- Tigger 5: Forth Friday;

If you want achieve your request feature in one trigger, I would suggest post this new [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory) to Data Factory. Data Factory product team may see it and think about add the feature.